# th:href Thymleaf inserting Variable in Link Text

Tags: html, spring, email, thymeleaf

Hey Guys so I'm using Thymelaf in my HTML Email template. I'm creating a hyperlink that looks like this:

```
<a th:href="@{https://example.com/#/login?username=__${username}__}">th:utext="https://example.com/#/login?username=${username}"</a>
```

The first part of the link works correctly and the username is correctly resolved by the template engine, but as you can see the link text doesn't map at all. I want the link text to be exactly like the link itself. Does anyone know how this can bed done?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a simple `<span>` tag :)

```
<a th:href="@{https://example.com/#/login?username=__${username}__}"><span th:text="'https://example.com/#/login?username='+${username}"></span></a></p>
```